# Явно задать тип данных numeric через sqldf в R

Tags: sql, sqlite, r

При работе в R с данными через пакет sqldf заметил такую особенность: при сохранении результата выборки в переменную (датафрейм) иногда столбцу с числами присваивается текстовый тип данных. Такое поведение замечено когда первые несколько значениий в столбце равны null.
Можно ли как-то явно задать числовой тип данных, чтоб избежать таких косяков?
Пробовал cast и round - не помогло.

Comment: На каком этапе задать? В готовой таблице можно сделать `as.numeric()`, такой  вариант не подходит?

Comment: Могли бы вы привести пример ?

Answer (score 3):

Если я правильно понял , вы хотите что бы колонка при выборе через `sqldf` строго была определенного типа , то можно сделать через параметр `method`

> (4) "name__class" which means that columns names that end in __class
>   with two underscores where class is an R class (such as Date) are
>   converted to that class and the __class portion is removed from the
>   column name. For example, sqldf("select a as x__Date from DF", method
>   = "name__class") would cause column a to be coerced to class Date and have the column name x.

*Свободный перевод*:

> "name__class" - позволяет определить класс для каждой колонки , где
>   класс указывается после двойного подчеркивания "__". При обработке
>   класс будет убран из названия колонки. Например `sqldf("select a as
>   x__Date from DF", method = "name__class")` вернет колонку `x` в формате
>   даты.

То есть вы можете для всех колонок указать тип в запросе.